# WCF Service times out from windows 8 unit test project

Tags: wcf, unit-testing, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

When the application is run, WCF service works as expected.
When the exact same code is called from a unit test project, the error below occurs.  Is there something special needed for windows 8 test projects to access the WCF service?

> Result Message:    Test method 
>   DataServiceTests.MyTest
>   threw exception:
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
>   System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException:  Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:56478/MyService/DataAccessService.  The connection
>   attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:42.0131535.  TCP error code
>   10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond  after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 
>   127.0.0.1:56478.  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:  A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time,  or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:56478

Integration test code:

```
DataAccess service = new DataAccess(
    new Uri(@"net.tcp://127.0.0.1:56478/MyServices/DataAccessService"));
var bob = service.GetData();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because this is a store app, it runs in a sandbox (AppContainer) and therefore certain things (like WCF) do not work from "unit tests" out of the box.  In order to get this to work, I had to add a Loopback Exemption to my development machine for the unit test project.

**Step 1**
Open the **Package.appxmanifest** file in the unit test project that calls the WCF service, and navigate to the **Packaging Tab**.  From there, note the **Package family name.**

[image: Package.appxmanifest]

**Step 2** Open the Visual Studio Command Prompt/Developer Prompt, as administrator, and paste this in `CheckNetIsolation LoopbackExempt -a -n=UnitTestProjectPackageFamilyName`, replacing the last bit with the actual package family name.

Answer (score 0):

Because you've not shared any of the related source, it's difficult to fully diagnose your problem. However ...

Are you sure your WCF service instance is started, running and accessible before your tests start running?

The error messages are pretty descriptive of what's going on:

> Could not connect to net.tcp://localhost:8111/MyService/DataAccessService
>
> The connection attempt lasted for a time span of 00:00:42.0131535.
>
> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 127.0.0.1:8111

Comment: Was more interested in your test code. What are you using to execute your tests? Xunit? MSTest? Other? Can your test code access an HTTP endpoint on your WCF service (vs. the TCP port you're currently exposing)?

Comment: Could you post some of your test code & test app config (if you're configuring your WCF client)? Does your service expose its endpoints using HTTP or TCP?

Comment: You can choose to configure your client, as per my Magic8Ball sample that we used to demo WCF while we built it :) https://github.com/bitcrazed/Magic8Ball/blob/master/src/Magic8BallApp/app.config. Sounds like you've written your test code to bind against the target service via code instead - that's fine, but trying to diagnose your problem without code is likely trying to fly a plane with your eyes closed ;)

Comment: Were you able to get the Magic8Ball running on your machine? I note that in your app, you're primarily using TCP - have you tried using HTTP instead?